# not displaying image which saved in mysql.i have tried lot of way to solve it, anybody? please help me?

Tags: php, mysql

//code to display image from mysql

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors',1);


    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require("connect.php");

     $query=mysql_query("select   *   from admission order by roll_no desc limit 1")or               
    die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   header("content-type:image/jpeg");

   echo $row['photo'];

   }
   ?>
```

Comment: And what happens, exactly? Any error message?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Asumed you have stored image as in table as blob type

```
 echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['photo']) . '" />';
```

In while loop:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($row['photo']) . '" />';    
}
```